# ReactJs - Same dates are repeating in recharts, how to make it as unique?

Tags: reactjs, date, graph, next.js, recharts

In React(Nextjs) application, I am using `recharts` with filters `1Day, 1Week, 1Month, 3Months, ALL`. On X-Axis dates are repeating like `Sep 8 Sep 9 Sep 9 Sep 10 Sep 11 Sep 11 Sep 12 Sep 12 Sep 13 Sep 14 Sep 14 Sep 15`, here data is coming for every 30 minutes like,

```
0: {date: "1631089801", price: "562.9511"}
1: {date: "1631091601", price: "5682.9511"}
2: {date: "1631093401", price: "56952.9601"}
...
```

Chart html part is,

```
const dateFormatString = activeFilter === '1d' ? 'HH:mm' : 'MMM D'
<LineChart
          width={1210}
          height={288}
          data={graphData}
          margin={{
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          }}
        >
          <XAxis
            dataKey="date"
            stroke="#D5DBDE"
            domain={[graphData[0]?.date, graphData[graphData.length - 1]?.date]} // first and last date
            ticks={graphData?.map(({ date }) => date)}
            tickFormatter={(tick) => moment(tick * 1000).format(dateFormatString)}
          />
  ...
</LineChart>
```

Why this issue is happening and how to fix it?
Dates should display like `Sep 9 Sep 10 Sep 11 Sep 12 Sep 13 Sep 14 Sep 15`.

Comment: that because you have different entries for the same day. i guess you should reduce your array summing prices for entries with same dates.

Comment: Can't we fix the date without summing the price entries?